# How to update hasMany associations when updating model?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

Is there a way to update an object (organization) and it’s associations (tasg) in a single call? In my case I have Orgs -> tags. One org can have many tags.

I can’t figure out how to update the tags as well as the organization in one simple call

```
function updateOrganization(db, stats) {
  return function (req, res) {
    let myOrg

    db.organization.findOne({
      where: {
        id: req.params.id
      },
      include: ['tags']
    })
      .then(org => {
        myOrg = org
        let promises = []

        if (req.body.tags) {
          req.body.tags.forEach(tag => {
            promises.push(org.createTag({ name: tag }))
          })
        }

        return Promise.all(promises)
      })
      .then(tags => {
        console.log('tags = ', tags)

        return myOrg.setTags(tags) <-- DOES NOT SEEM TO BE WORKING
      })
     .then(updatedOrg => {
       console.log('updatedOrg.get() = ', updatedOrg.get()) <-- DOES NOT CONTAIN NEW TAGS
       console.log('myOrg final = ', myOrg.get()) <-- DOES NOT CONTAIN NEW TAGS
       return res.status(HttpStatus.OK).send(myOrg)
      })
      .catch(err => {
        req.log.error(err)
        return handleErr(res, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, err.message)
      })
  }
}
```

**NOTE**: It looks like the line `promises.push(org.createTag({ name: tag }))` is actually creating the tags and the line `return myOrg.setTags(tags)` is not necessary. When i fetch this record with a `findOne` query, all the tags do actually exist. So why don't they appear when in my log statements which is the output of `updatedOrg`?

Comment: as long as I know , not possible in single call with `sequelize.js`.

Comment: I believe calling `org.setTags(...)` after `org.save` is your only option

Comment: I updated my question with your suggestion and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Does `org.createTag({ name: tag }).then(x => console.log(x))` output the contents of `tag`? What's the result?

Comment: Yes it does actually produce the output of the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use something like this:

```
function updateOrganization(db, stats) {
  return async (req, res) => {
    try {
      // Get the organization + associations
      const org = await Organization.find({
        where: { id: req.params.id },
        include: ['tags'],
        limit: 1, // added this because in the 4.42.0 version '.findOne()' is deprecated
      });

      // Check if we have any tags specified in the body
      if(req.body.tags) {
        await Promise.all(req.body.tags.map(tag => org.createTag({ name: tag })));
      }

      return res.status(HttpStatus.OK).send(org.reload()); // use '.reload()' to refresh associated data
    } catch(err) {
      req.log.error(err);
      return handleErr(res, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, err.message);
    }
  }
}
```

You can read more about `.reload()` [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#instance-method-reload).

Also I recommend you to use Sequelize Transactions in the future, it will be very easy to control your app flow.

Comment: Baby steps. If i can't figure out simple associations i surely don't want to introduce transactions yet. `reload()` was the piece i was missing!

Comment: And why is sequlize not following semver and deprecating things in a minor version!!!!! Yet another reason i hate sequlize!!

Comment: And how do you know 4.42.0 deprecates `.findOne()`? It's not in the changelog https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/releases

Comment: I love Sequelize, if you have problems with it you can set a fixed version. About the `.findOne()`, I used the 4.42.0 recently and I got a console log about it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want a "hasMany" relationship. Usually tags are shared, and the Org would have a "[belongsToMany](https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/v3/api/associations/belongs-to-many/)" relationship. Please post your models and schema, and if possible, a working example (with connection to a database with your schema) or a link to one.

In any case, I believe `createTag` is only going to work if the tag does not already exist. If the tag exists, you need to `setTags` or `addTags`, passing in the tag objects or their primary key IDs.

Comment: My associations may not quite be right, but that's not the ultimate reason for my issue at hand.